# Kotlin and jvm: object OR class instance?

Tags: android, jvm, kotlin

```
object SampleObject{
   fun getSampleText(): String = "123"
}

class SampleClass {
   fun getSampleText(): String = "123"
}
```

There are no fields, methods only.

`ActivityA` starts `ActivityB`.
In `ActivityB` there is a call to `SampleObject.getSampleText()` and `SampleClass().getSampleText()`. Then `ActivityB` finishes.

What is the best practice? To use object or to use class instances?

Answer (score 1):

If the function is pure (i.e. no side-effects), then code it at the top-level. No need to explicitly create a class/object in Kotlin.

The compiler will produce a class that contains your method as a static method, and therefore has the same lifecyle as all static methods.

An Object contains a static reference to a constructed version of itself, and the class has your function. Again, the class/method will exist for life of JVM

Comment: nono, fixed String is only for example, consider there is some calculating inside the method. In example I use this method call once only when second Activity launched.
QUESTION IS: After ActivityB is closed, in case with Class instance - GC will collect instance, cuz' there's no strong reference to SampleClass instance. What will be with SampleObject in memory? It's a singleton = how long it will be stored in memory?

Comment: Completely rewrote. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: where did you get this information about kotlin compiler and lifecycle on jvm? please, share

Comment: IntellJ has a 'show bytecode' for Kotlin built-in. On the view that shows bytecode, there's a de-compile that will show the code as Java code. Hopefully Android studio has similar functionality. Very helpful for understanding what the Kotlin compiler will produce. If Android Studio doesn't have it, install IntelliJ Community Edition with the Kotlin plugin.